# Move Control Beyond Screen Resolution VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

If you move a control or form beyond the capability of what the screen can display, where does it actually go.

Here is an example I have been testing as I continue to learn.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Button2.Location = New Point(23000, 200)
    Button2.Text = Button2.Location.X
    MsgBox(Button2.Text)
End Sub
```

When button1 is pressed it moves button2 to location 23000 on the x axis which is obviously beyond the screen resolution width.

My question is where is button2 been moved to if you know what I mean.

Comment: It has been moved to x 23000 and y 200.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember what controls really are: some memory, a GDI resource, and some pixels painted on the screen.

If a control moves off the visible area the memory and GDI resources remain. The only difference is when it comes time to paint; in this case, since it's not visible, nothing is drawn.

However, just because it's not drawn doesn't mean it's not there. You can still get focus on the item and click it by tabbing (or other keyboard shortcuts) through the controls. If you just want to hide the item, you're better off setting `.Enabled` and `.Visible` to `False`.